# understand a C socket instruction

Tags: c, sockets, struct

This is a statement that I haven't completely understood.

```
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct in_addr*)(hp->h_addr)) -> s_addr;
```

Does this mean that:

1. i put `hp` into `h_addr`
2. typecast of type `struct in_addr*` of `hp->h_addr`
3. all of this have been copied into `s_addr`

So serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr contain the hostname and the ip address of choosen host.
Is this right?

(PS: hp is `struct hostent *hp ; hp=gethostbyname(argv[1]);`)

Comment: `gethostbyname()` is deprecated, you might consider using `getaddrinfo()` instead.

Comment: i know, i've read about this but i need a simple implementation so i will study getaddrinfo (that it is more complex) in a (near) future :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand [the arrow operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/as400clr91.htm).

Essentially, it gives you access to the member of a structure when you have a pointer to that structure.

Thus, `hp->h_addr` gives you access to the `h_addr` member of the `hostent` structure that `hp` points to. Then, you're casting that member to a `in_addr *` and dereferencing that so that you can access the `s_addr` member of the `in_addr` structure.

Answer (score 2):

(1) is wrong. `hp->h_addr` is short for `(*hp).h_addr`. It's a dereference plus a member selection.

In English, one might say "Copy `hp`'s `h_addr` into `serv_addr`'s `s_addr`. This requires a cast."